# Android - How to create a custom (different) spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I'm trying to build and populate a spinner. I have a problem populating it, it gives me the error "The code for the static initializer is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit". I need all items I've put inside spinner. My spinner is set in this way:

```
public class Names
{
    public static final String ALL_NAMES = "All names";
    public static final String NAMES = "NAMES";
    public static final String OBJECT = "OBJECT";
    private String names;
    private String object;

    public Names(String names, String object){
        super();
        this.names = names;
        this.object = object;
    }

    public String getNames() { return names; }
    public String getObject() { return object; }

    public static final Names[] DB = new Names[]{ 
        new Names("Albert","Person"),
        new Names("Bobby","Animal"),...
```

where the names in second quotes are what I can choose from my spinner and the names in first quotes are the results of my choice. I'd like to make a thing like ExpandableList where I insert a "Parent String" and then all the items for that kind of "Parent String". This is an example:

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private String[] groups = { "Persons", "Dogs", "Cats" };
    private String[][] children = {
        { "Albert", "Robert", "Paul" },
        { "Yuri", "Rocky" },
        { "Lisa" },
    };
```

Is that possible using a custom spinner? I hope you understood what I meant and wrote. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So when the spinner displays the drop down you want it to display the objects of a name?

Comment: I'd like that it displays "Persons" "Dogs" etc. and when I tap on an item it'll give me all results for that item. Example: If I tap on "Persons" from my spinner drop down it will give me in a ListView the results like "Albert" Robert" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is failing because you've used more than 65535 bytes in your static initialiser, or more specifically using a Java source file to enter the..

```
 public static final Names[] DB = new Names[]{ 
    new Names("Albert","Person"),
    new Names("Bobby","Animal"),...
```

Will run you into limitations within the compiler / language spec - ie from the JVM spec

> "The amount of code per non-native, non-abstract method is limited to 65536 
>   bytes by the sizes of the indices in the exception_table of the Code 
>   attribute (§4.7.3), in the LineNumberTable attribute (§4.7.8), and in the 
>   LocalVariableTable attribute (§4.7.9). "

This would probably work perfectly well if you stored the data in a database or in a file (which really should be how you're doing this, it's really clunky to be doing it in the java source file) that you load - note that you can run into the 65536 byte limit even if your code takes less than that many bytes, because it's the way it stores it internally that you run into.

You can verify that this is the case if you change your code to read:

```
 public static final Names[] DB = new Names[]{ 
    new Names("Albert","Person"),
    new Names("Bobby","Animal")};
```

And run it with that (having deleted the rest of it).

Comment: I know is that the problem because I deleted many of new Names("", "") to run my application. So I'm looking for another way to use all my datas (with a spinner if it's possible), even those I deleted.

Comment: I tried to follow this example http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html but where I need to put results for what I choose from my spinner?